# Gaussian Mixture Model

Tags: python, expectation-maximization, gaussian-mixture-distribution, scipy

with the following code I fit a Gaussian Mixture Model to arbitrarily created data. The code is working. The only thing I encounter is that during the calculation of the [multivariate_normal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html) I encounter the error that I have a singular matrix.

The code is the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use('fivethirtyeight')
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal


# 0. Create dataset
X,Y = make_blobs(cluster_std=0.5,random_state=20,n_samples=1000,centers=10)

# Stratch dataset to get ellipsoid data
X = np.dot(X,np.random.RandomState(0).randn(2,2))


class EMM:

    def __init__(self,X,number_of_sources,iterations):
        self.iterations = iterations
        self.number_of_sources = number_of_sources
        self.X = X
        self.mu = None
        self.pi = None
        self.cov = None
        self.XY = None


    # Define a function which runs for i iterations:
    def run(self):

        x,y = np.meshgrid(np.sort(self.X[:,0]),np.sort(self.X[:,1]))
        self.XY = np.array([x.flatten(),y.flatten()]).T



        # 1. Set the initial mu, covariance and pi values
        self.mu = np.random.randint(min(self.X[:,0]),max(self.X[:,0]),size=(self.number_of_sources,len(self.X[0]))) # This is a nxm matrix since we assume n sources (n Gaussians) where each has m dimensions
        self.cov = np.zeros((self.number_of_sources,len(X[0]),len(X[0]))) # We need a nxmxm covariance matrix for each source since we have m features --> We create symmetric covariance matrices with ones on the digonal
        for dim in range(len(self.cov)):
            np.fill_diagonal(self.cov[dim],5)
        print(print(np.linalg.inv(self.cov[0])))

        self.pi = np.ones(self.number_of_sources)/self.number_of_sources # Are "Fractions"
        log_likelihoods = [] # In this list we store the log likehoods per iteration and plot them in the end to check if
                             # if we have converged

        # Plot the initial state    
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
        ax0 = fig.add_subplot(111)
        ax0.scatter(self.X[:,0],self.X[:,1])
        for m,c in zip(self.mu,self.cov):
            multi_normal = multivariate_normal(mean=m,cov=c)
            ax0.contour(np.sort(self.X[:,0]),np.sort(self.X[:,1]),multi_normal.pdf(self.XY).reshape(len(self.X),len(self.X)),colors='black',alpha=0.3)
            ax0.scatter(m[0],m[1],c='grey',zorder=10,s=100)

        for i in range(self.iterations):               

            # E Step
            r_ic = np.zeros((len(self.X),len(self.cov)))

            for m,co,p,r in zip(self.mu,self.cov,self.pi,range(len(r_ic[0]))):
                mn = multivariate_normal(mean=m,cov=co)
                r_ic[:,r] = p*mn.pdf(self.X)/np.sum([pi_c*multivariate_normal(mean=mu_c,cov=cov_c).pdf(X) for pi_c,mu_c,cov_c in zip(self.pi,self.mu,self.cov)],axis=0)


            # M Step

            # Calculate the new mean vector and new covariance matrices, based on the probable membership of the single x_i to classes c --> r_ic
            self.mu = []
            self.cov = []
            self.pi = []
            log_likelihood = []

            for c in range(len(r_ic[0])):
                m_c = np.sum(r_ic[:,c],axis=0)
                mu_c = (1/m_c)*np.sum(self.X*r_ic[:,c].reshape(len(self.X),1),axis=0)
                self.mu.append(mu_c)

                # Calculate the covariance matrix per source based on the new mean
                self.cov.append((1/m_c)*np.dot((np.array(r_ic[:,c]).reshape(len(self.X),1)*(self.X-mu_c)).T,(self.X-mu_c)))
                # Calculate pi_new which is the "fraction of points" respectively the fraction of the probability assigned to each source 
                self.pi.append(m_c/np.sum(r_ic)) # Here np.sum(r_ic) gives as result the number of instances. This is logical since we know 
                                                # that the columns of each row of r_ic adds up to 1. Since we add up all elements, we sum up all
                                                # columns per row which gives 1 and then all rows which gives then the number of instances (rows) 
                                                # in X --> Since pi_new contains the fractions of datapoints, assigned to the sources c,
                                                # The elements in pi_new must add up to 1



            # Log likelihood
            log_likelihoods.append(np.log(np.sum([k*multivariate_normal(self.mu[i],self.cov[j]).pdf(X) for k,i,j in zip(self.pi,range(len(self.mu)),range(len(self.cov)))])))



        fig2 = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
        ax1 = fig2.add_subplot(111) 
        ax1.plot(range(0,self.iterations,1),log_likelihoods)
        plt.show()


    def predict(self,Y):
        # PLot the point onto the fittet gaussians
        fig3 = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
        ax2 = fig3.add_subplot(111)
        ax2.scatter(self.X[:,0],self.X[:,1])
        for m,c in zip(self.mu,self.cov):
            multi_normal = multivariate_normal(mean=m,cov=c)
            ax2.contour(np.sort(self.X[:,0]),np.sort(self.X[:,1]),multi_normal.pdf(self.XY).reshape(len(self.X),len(self.X)),colors='black',alpha=0.3)
            ax2.scatter(m[0],m[1],c='grey',zorder=10,s=100)
            for y in Y:
                ax2.scatter(y[0],y[1],c='orange',zorder=10,s=100)
        prediction = []        
        for m,c in zip(self.mu,self.cov):        
            prediction.append(multivariate_normal(mean=m,cov=c).pdf(Y)/np.sum([multivariate_normal(mean=mean,cov=cov).pdf(Y) for mean,cov in zip(self.mu,self.cov)]))
        plt.show()
        return prediction


EMM = EMM(X,10,20)     
EMM.run()
EMM.predict([[0.5,0.5]])
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

So is there a way of how I can prevent to get a singular matrix (which is not invertible and hence the calculation of the multivariate_normal() fails since there we have to calculate the inverse of the covariance matrix) or is the only way how I can solve this issue by calling the function multiple times and choose the solution where I don't get an error? Appreciate any help!
Edit: I know that I can set the parameter allow_singluar==True (though I don't know what is done in the background here) but this sometimes does lead to confusing results... so there should be a more accurate/secure way

EDIT: Looking up the docs for [sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html#sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture) we can see that there is a parameter *reg_covar* which is responsible to keep the invertability of the covariance matrix. So the question is, how can I implement this in my code?

Comment: Does pseudo inverse work?

Comment: Since the initial covariance matrix is a multiple of the identity matrix, the inverse is the same as this matrix. Hence the "non-invertabiity" must arise during the calculations, that is during the updating of the covariance matrix bsed on self.mu and r_ic

Answer (score 1):

This answer does not answer the question how scipy allows for singularity and also not what conseqences this behavious has on the results but it gives a little bit more insight into what is going on during the calculations:

EDIT: I have posted an detailed answer on what is happening when we run into singularity issues during the calculations of a GMM [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/219302/singularity-issues-in-gaussian-mixture-model/359730#359730)